# FPDF/PHP - Adding bottom border to table before next page

Tags: php, fpdf

I have a form generated by FPDF which creates multiple rows based on the client's payment records. I want it to create a bottom border when it has finished creating the last row in the current page. (See below, just above the page number) Is there an FPDF function for this?

[image]

Comment: You could do this in `Footer()`.

Comment: @Olivier I suppose yes. But won't that add the border to every page?

Comment: You need to set and check a flag appropriately, e.g. `if($this->tableInProgress) ...`.